# Каким тегом писать заголовки в карточек товара на сайте?

Tags: html, css, seo, микроразметка

На странице много карточек с продуктами. Для seo логичнее использовать теги h1-h6, но их можно использовать в ограниченном количестве. Как быть? Если заменить на span - это нормально?

Comment: Да, нормально, никаких проблем с этим не будет

Comment: _их можно использовать в ограниченном количестве_ - почему ты так решил?

Comment: @Grundy читал где-то, честно возможно я ошибаюсь. Допустим h1 я точно знаю, что на странице может быть только 1 раз

Comment: ограничения только на h1. все остальные можно использовать

Answer (score -1):

Замени на span или используй h3, h4